# how to change the URL for wordpress

Tags: apache, wordpress

After installing wordpress on my staging Ubuntu server the URL to it is "mydomain/wordpress". I'd like it to be "mydomain/blog". Most companies use that convention. will I just have to change the folder name (or rather symbolic link name) leading to where wordpress is installed from "wordpress" to "blog"?

What if I wanted blog.mydomain.com instead? where do I make this change? Apache config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to do it in two steps. go to site-admin-settings-general to change your wordrpess address and site address to yourdomain.com/blog,  and then use FTP to change the folder name. this should work.

some domain provider support accessing you subdomain like blog.youdomain.com when you have a folder name blog under the root path.

Answer (score 0):

Simply changing the folder name in FTP or the site URL in Admin>>Settings will break WP.

See various docs: [Moving WordPress « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) and [How to Move WordPress Blog to New Domain or Location  »  My Digital Life](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/10/01/how-to-move-wordpress-blog-to-new-domain-or-location/) and  [Changing The Site URL « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL)

Subdomains depend on the limitations of your hosting account; ask them.

Answer (score -1):

Changing the name of the symlink from wordpress to blog will work.